# JButton, JLabel, and JTable menu layout trouble

Tags: java, layout, jtable, jbutton, jlabel

I'm trying to create a side menu that has a small button at the top, two different size tables beneath it (the first one above the second), and then two JLabels beneath that (again, the first JLabel being on top of the other).

```
<Button>
<Table1>
<Table2>
<Label1>
<Label2>
```

The problem I am running into is that whatever layout I use, one of the components will run into some sort of trouble, e.g. tables messing up, button expanding to fill the whole line, being unable to move the JLabel.
What layout should I use for the menu I desire?

Here is a copy of my current code:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Hello{
final Object[][] data = new Object[7][6];
String[] columnNames = {"Player", "Taxi", "Bus", "Undrgrd", "Secret", "Double"};

String[] mrXcolumns = {"Move","Transport"};
final Object[][] mrXdata = new Object[24][2];

final JFrame w = new JFrame();

int whosGo;
int roundNumber;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hello hello = new Hello();
    hello.run();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void run()
    {
        JPanel sidepanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JButton newgame = new JButton("New Game");          
        JTable ticketTable = new JTable( data, columnNames );
        JScrollPane ticketView = new JScrollPane( ticketTable );
        ticketView.setBounds(25,50,300,150);

        JTable mrXTable = new JTable(mrXdata, mrXcolumns);
        JScrollPane moveView = new JScrollPane( mrXTable );
        moveView.setBounds(25,210,300,400);

        JLabel turn = new JLabel("Detective "+whosGo+"'s go");
        JLabel round = new JLabel("ROUND: " +roundNumber);

        sidepanel.setBounds(1018,0,382,809);
        sidepanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        sidepanel.add(newgame);
        sidepanel.add(ticketView);
        sidepanel.add(moveView);
        sidepanel.add(turn);
        sidepanel.add(round);

        w.add(sidepanel);
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(w.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1400,809));
        w.setLayout(null);
        w.pack();
        w.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
```

}

Comment: Did you try GridBagLayout? If you want a lot of control over your UI, GBL is the best, without question.

Comment: Try `BoxLayout`, i use it for vertical layout all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of possible ways to achieve this depending on the desired result.

### You Could...

Use a [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) which will allow you to add components into a single column.  The downside to this is the width of each component will be the width of the parent container and each component will be given an equal amount of the height (divided amongst the components);

```
sidepanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
sidepanel.add(newgame);
sidepanel.add(ticketView);
sidepanel.add(moveView);
sidepanel.add(turn);
sidepanel.add(round);
```

### You Could...

Use a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) which will allow you to control how components fill there column

```
sidepanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
// One component per row...
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
// Fill the available column space, this does not mean
// fill to fit the available parent container width though
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
sidepanel.add(newgame, gbc);
sidepanel.add(ticketView, gbc);
sidepanel.add(moveView, gbc);
sidepanel.add(turn, gbc);
sidepanel.add(round, gbc);
```

The drawback to this is is that, by default, the `GridBagLayout` will align all it's components to the center position of the container.  There are tricks you can employ to change this, but it's a little messy

### You Could...

Use the `VertcialLayout` from [SwingX](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/) libraries

Comment: GridBagLayout does seem like the way to go! Using your code you supplied gets everything on top of eachother, but the tabled are compacted so are unreadable, do you know how to fix this?
Thanks for the great reply :)

Comment: @user3408100 Start by avoiding `null` layouts

Comment: Do you mean the tables have a null layout?

Comment: No, I mean that you are using a `null` layout on you application frame, `w.setLayout(null);`, which is highly unadvisiable

Comment: Okay, I've set the layout of w to a BorderLayout and added the sidepanel to the east, but still the tables are like this: 
http://gyazo.com/3b70239da9098d8a0694629299ad04ab

Comment: It "looks" like you're adding the table (and some other components) to another panel before adding that to the center position of the window, but that doesn't reflect the example code you posted, so it's difficault to be sure

Comment: nope :/ just adding those components to sidepanel like in your code above, and then adding sidepanel to w

Comment: Are you able to provide an example

Comment: Wasn't really sure of the best way to send this, it was too long for a comment:
http://gyazo.com/c987392cc92f9b6fac07678e12492380
Thanks once again for continuing to help :)!

Comment: I think I see it now. This will depend on what you want to achieve, but you could set table to have a greater weight of the vertical space, using `gbc.weighty = ...;` some value between 0 & 1. Just remember to reset it back to 0 before adding the next component. Equally, you can effect the horizontal weight with `weightx`

Comment: ah, things are moving now! Still not getting the desired results, for example by doing this:
http://gyazo.com/42e09d28e9c26fd60a54085c87c2c92d
I got the following result: http://gyazo.com/06ccff8dd006e9125b7ae279ee33cefe
So the tables still aren't expanding

Comment: You can also use `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH` to make the components fill the cells

Comment: ah brilliant! I think I get how to distribute the weight in Y direction now! :D Just struggling with the X, seems like if I change the xweight value of any one of the components they all just fill the container:
http://gyazo.com/0e48ea9dd2aeb7e332a0c6def60e1c71
code: http://gyazo.com/99e9ec6e06ec8b8f9941ac41dce93e43

Comment: You might need to change the `fill` property so some `fill` `BOTH`, some `fill` `HORIZONTALLY`, some `fill` `VERTICALLY` ;)

Comment: Ahah! genius! :D Thank you ever so much for helping me out- I know I kind of went off topic from my original question!
Cheers!!